# Regex to capture 2 sets of 8 non capital letters, sandwiched by dots

Tags: regex, re2

I'm hoping to capture some rando weirdness that is being dynamically generated and stuffed at the end of my temporary ASP files. The weirdness is a pattern of two sets of eight characters (appear to be all non capital letters) sandwiched by dots.

I am trying to find the best regex to capture both sets of 8 non capital letter characters, sandwiched by dots.

Here is my current regex:

```
\.([^A-Z]{8})\.
```

My current regex works ok to capture the first set, but doesn't capture the second set. I believe it's because the dot is getting eaten after the first match and so there's no dot to trigger the second set from matching.

How can I improve this regex so it captures both sets of dynamic weirdness? Would greatly appreciate any help folks can provide!

Data set to match:

| String | Expected match |
| --- | --- |
| \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\svc_pr30\701d8ff1\10cc0653\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.**cdcab7d2.3sl-aaqs**.dll | cdcab7d2.3sl-aaqs |
| \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\svc_pr21\a201b637\20c58f14\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.**cdcab7d2.xqj2w-wv**.dll | cdcab7d2.xqj2w-wv |
| \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\web_releaseapi\638ee986\2f0d9ef4\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.**cdcab7d2.-qsn3y9x**.dll | cdcab7d2.-qsn3y9x |
| \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\web_releaseapi\638ee986\2f0d9ef4\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.**cdcab7d2.pyn4enbe**.dll | cdcab7d2.pyn4enbe |
| \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\cmuserservice_windowsauth\a10d69fc\d9424d7d\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.**cdcab7d2.thhlx9xi**.dll | cdcab7d2.thhlx9xi |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\.([^A-Z.]{8}\.[^A-Z.]{8})\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/29fX8M/1). *Details*:

- `\.` - a dot
- `([^A-Z.]{8}\.[^A-Z.]{8})` - Group 1: eight chars other than a dot and uppercase ASCII letters, a `.` and then again eight chars other than a dot and uppercase ASCII letters
- `\.` - a dot.

Group 1 values for each tested string will be:

```
cdcab7d2.3sl-aaqs
cdcab7d2.xqj2w-wv
cdcab7d2.-qsn3y9x
cdcab7d2.pyn4enbe
cdcab7d2.thhlx9xi
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of focusing on the non capital, your dataset actually extracts: all small letters, numbers, and dash. Separated by a dot
And you want to extract just before the **.dll**
So you can use this regex to extract.

```
([a-z0-9-]+?\.[-a-z0-9]+?)\.dll
```

Then for your result, simply get group 1 of the regex matches.
I presume you know about regex grouping.

[See the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LhFHd9/1)